# Proof from John Lee on the equivalence of topological boundary and manifold boundary for regular domains

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am having difficulty following the conclusion of the proof below from John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Here a regular domain in $M$ is a properly embedded codimension-$0$ submanifolds with boundary.

Here $F$ is the inclusion map from $D \hookrightarrow M$, which is a smooth embedding.

I understand the proof before the final sentence. But how do we conclude from here that every neighborhood of $p$ intersects both $D$ and $M\backslash D$?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Every ball around the origin contains points with $x^m>0$ and points as well with $x^m<0$.

Comment: @Berci Where is the fact that $V_0 \cap D$ consists of all the points in $V_0$ whose $x^n$ coordinate is nonnegative used? And I can't see why every ball containing points with $x^m>0$ and $x^m<0$ indicate that every ball intersects with $M \backslash D$.

Comment: What is a 'boundary chart' and how does $U$ relate to $V$?

Comment: @Berci I am confused with the construction here. We need an arbitrary neighborhood of $p$ to intersect both $D$ and $M \backslash D$, but instead we have shown that we can find a neighborhood $V_0$ of p in $M$ whose intersection with $D$ is all the points in $V_0$ whose $n$th coordinate is $0$. This suggests some relationship with the boundary chart, perhaps that $V_0$ restricted to $D$ becomes a boundary chart for $D$? But how does this answer the final sentence?

Comment: Note that the coordinate maps together (that is, $\psi$) form a *diffeomorphism* $M\to\Bbb R^n$, so every open neighborhood of $p$ corresponds to an open neighborhood of $0$, and that contains a ball around $0$.

Comment: @Berci I know that but I can't see how that answers my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this proof confusing, too. Here is my understanding: we have that $D$ is an embedded submanifold of $M.$ Take any $p\in \partial D$. Then, there is a chart $\textit{in M},\ $ say, $(V,(x^1,\cdots,x^n))$ about $p$ such that $(D\cap V,(x^1,\cdots,x^k))$ is a boundary (slice) chart for $D$ about $p$. Thus, $q\in D\cap V\Rightarrow x^k(q)\ge 0$ But $\text{dim}\ D=\text{dim}\ M\Rightarrow k=n$, and so $x^n\ge 0.$ Now, $M$ is a manifold without boundary, which means that there must be a point $q\in V$  such that $x^n(q)<0$, (because $(V,(x^1,\cdots,x^n))$ is a chart about $p$ in $M$), which in turn implies that $q\notin D$ (because $D\cap V$ has all $x^n\ge 0$). Therefore, $V$ contains points in $D$ and in $M\setminus D$.

Comment: I think it should be $x^k \ge 0$ and $x^n \ge 0$ since at $p$ we should have $x^n=0$?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician yes, indeed. Thanks!